# Ruby on Rails: OR operator in devise, not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise

Am I doing this correctly in devise/registrations/shared/_links?

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' || controller_name != 'registrations' || controller_name != 'static' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

It showing sign in when I have tested

```
<%= controller_name %>
```

and it displays `registrations` or `static`

Thanks

Comment: have u tried the solution mentioned in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show link only if controller_name is not equal to mentioned strings, you should not use **OR** operator.

In your example mentioned above, if controller_name is registrations or static, then it is not equal to 'sessions'. The condition is passed and it shows the link.

**Either check controller_name does not exist with in array of given strings:**

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) unless %w(sessions registrations static).include?(controller_name) %>
```

**Or use AND operator:**

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) if controller_name != 'sessions' && controller_name != 'registrations' && controller_name != 'static' %>
```

It should work perfect for you.

Comment: ahhhh yes, this is logic makes sense. Thank you.